# Go Pointers - append values to slice via pointer

Tags: pointers, go, slice

I have a struct ProductData and its instance p which has a slice attribute :

```
type ProductInfo struct {
    TopAttributes []map[string]interface{}
}
```

I want to set TopAttributes as follows

```
func (p *ProductInfo) setAttributeData() {
    key := "key"
    value := "value"
    setAttribute(p.TopAttributes, key, value)
}

func setAttribute(p []map[string]interface{}, key string, value interface{}) {
    val := map[string]interface{}{
        key: value,
    }
    p = append(p, val)
}
```

### But this does not seem to work.

However, there is another way which works fine when I define a method as:

```
   func (p *ProductInfo) setAttributeData() {
    key := "key"
    value := "value"
    p.setAttribute(key, value)
}

func (p *ProductInfo) setAttribute(key string, value interface{}) {
    val := map[string]interface{}{
        key: value,
    }
    p.TopAttributes = append(p.TopAttributes, val)
}
```

I want to find out why it is not working. There were no errors in my code, but the data coming was empty.
I am trying to do this to make it a generic function as I have another BottomAttributes which has to be set the same way.

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Viable, Complete Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Based on the code you've given us, this shouldn't even compile. You're referencing attrData, did you mean attrCode?

Comment: I have given the required code.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`append` returns a reference to the appended-to slice. This is because it could point to a new location in memory if it needed to be resized.

In your first example, you are updating the variable passed to your `setAttribute` function, but that's it. The only reference is lost when that function exits.

It works in the second example because that variable lives in your struct, and is thus updated.

You can fix the first version by using a pointer:

```
func (p *ProductInfo) setAttributeData() {
    key := "key"
    value := "value"
    setAttribute(&p.TopAttributes, key, value)
}

func setAttribute(p *[]map[string]interface{}, key string, value interface{}) {
    val := map[string]interface{}{
        key: value,
    }
    *p = append(*p, val)
}
```

Comment: I tried the above, but missed the *p = append(*p, val)  part. Thanks, it is working now.

Comment: I have another question - All slices and maps are passed as  references. So when I pass the reference of TopAttributes (which is a slice) and setting the value as p = append(p, val) , shouldn't it work. This is also updating the reference in a way.

Comment: You are updating a reference. But only the reference that setAttribute sees. When you use a pointer to that "reference", you're updating the variable that setAttributeData has. In C terms, it's a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to append a `map` value which is used as a function parameter, so it has a local scope, accessible only within the function. Because this is referenced by value and not by pointer address, it's access is restricted only to it's local scope.

Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices, and so the value of parameter `p` is nil; it doesn't point to an initialized map.

To point it to a map you have to access trough it's pointer:

```
func (p *ProductInfo) setAttributeData() {
    key := "key"
    value := "value"
    setAttribute(p.TopAttributes, key, value)
}

func setAttribute(p *[]map[string]interface{}, key string, value interface{}) {
    val := map[string]interface{}{
        key: value,
    }
    *p = append(*p, val)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Shortly, though we can use slice to modify the source data, but for slice itself, when as an argument for function, it just pass a copy into the function.
so, your code like this

```
func test(i int) {
    i = i + 1
}
var a int = 3
test(a)
```